# How to work out which widget to target with Qt stylesheets

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I'm attempting to use Qt stylesheets to style a reasonably complex UI. So far things are going reasonably well, but I'm running into a difficulty:

How can I work out what widget name I should be targeting for a particular part of a UI? For example, if I want to change the font size in the cells of a QTableView, do I write a style that targets QTableView? or perhaps QAbstractScrollArea? or perhaps QAbstractitemDelegate?  As it turns out none of these seem to work - I assume this can be done, but it's a case of working out what the magic combination of widgets is to target the right part of the UI.

The [style sheet guide](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/stylesheet.html) helps somewhat, but seems to be missing a lot of information - the example for customising QTableView only mentions customising the cell background colour, and does not mention changing font colour, size, face, grid lines etc.

Am i missing something here? Perhaps Using stylesheets is the wrong way to go? I certainly hope not, since the alternative (deriving from  QStyle) seems much more complicated.

Cheers,

Comment: So are saying that calling, for example, setStyleSheet("QTableView { background-color: yellow }") on your QApplication instance does nothing? Can you give examples of what you have tried?

Comment: No, sorry - I'm just saying that trying to manupulate certain properties (font size in my case) does nothing when applied to the table view.

Comment: Could you post your code? 

What happens when you do something like this: 

 QTableView {
     font-size: 12px;
     selection-color: black;
     selection-background-color: black;
 }

Comment: There's really not much code to post - I'm just applying the contents of a stylesheet file to QApplication. When I try your code I get a warning that the property "selection-color" is unknown, and I get black backgrounds to selected rows.

Comment: Oops -- selection-color was a mistake. Does setting font-size work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering of items in an item view is done by the delegate. Since Qt 4.4, the built-in item views use a style-able delegate implementation by default (see this [blog post](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2007/11/01/qstyleditemdelegate-styling-item-views/)), but it seems that you want more control that it allows you.

In that case, make sure that your model's data() method returns proper values for the appearance related [ItemDataRoles](http://doc.trolltech.com/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) (I think that Qt::FontRole will be especially of interest to you). If that is not enough, or if it's not possible, you should subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.trolltech.com/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and reimplement its paint() method.

As to grid lines, QTableView has the [gridStyle](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtableview.html#gridStyle-prop) property.

Comment: Hi,

That blog post helps a lot however, the example they're using changes the background colour and border - I seem unable to change the row height or font size.

Comment: Thomi: Like I motioned in the answer, those things are not (as far as I know) style-able. Make sure your model returns a QFont instance as data for the FontRole, and a QSize instance as data for the SizeHintRole